# android with ant licensing library dependencies

Tags: android, ant, android-lvl

I need to use ANT with Android building process because at the end I need to create two versions of application (FULL & LITE).
When I created new project with command-line tools it generates for me all necessary build files (build.xml, local.properties, build.properties and default.properties, oh and also proguard.cfg). My full version of app need a market licensing library (which is located on my ${sdk.dir}/extras/google/market_licensing/library. So in Eclipse I define where this library is and it works if I run my app from Eclipse.
Now if I run ant script on my app

```
${my.project-home}$ ant
Buildfile: ${my.project-home}/build.xml
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 10
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.1-update1
    [setup] API level: 7
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:

BUILD FAILED
${my.project-home}/build.xml:77: ../../../android-sdk-mac_86/extras/google/market_licensing/library resolve to a path with no default.properties file for project ${my.project-home}
```

My default.properties look like

```
target=android-7
android.library=false
android.library.reference.1=../../../android-sdk-mac_86/extras/google/market_licensing/library
```

And my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyMeasures">

<!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
     tool.
     It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
     Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />

    <!-- The build.properties file can be created by you and is never touched
         by the 'android' tool. This is the place to change some of the
         default property values used by the Ant rules.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <!-- The default.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.
         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="default.properties" />


    <!-- Required pre-setup import -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml" />


<!-- extension targets. Uncomment the ones where you want to do custom work
     in between standard targets -->

    <target name="-pre-build">
    </target>
    <target name="-pre-compile">
    </target>

<!--    [This is typically used for code obfuscation.
     Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
     If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir}]
    <target name="-post-compile">
    </target>
-->

    <!-- Execute the Android Setup task that will setup some properties
         specific to the target, and import the build rules files.

         The rules file is imported from
            <SDK>/tools/ant/
         Depending on the project type it can be either:
         - main_rules.xml
         - lib_rules.xml
         - test_rules.xml

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <setup> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole script.
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, *after* the <setup> task
             - disable the import of the rules by changing the setup task
               below to <setup import="false" />.
             - customize to your needs.
    -->
    <setup />

</project>
```

The only thing I do in build.xml for now is that I uncommented `-pre-build` and `-pre-compile` but they do nothing... I also tried to comment them back and it is the same result.

Have anyone used market licensing library with ant?

Answer (score 2):

little bit older topic but maybe it helps to someone. I had same problem and finally discovered source of troubles

**system:** win7, last Eclipse and old android tools

created build.xml with

```
android update project --path .
```

added library(ies) to default.properties like

```
android.library.reference.1=..\dir\MyLibrary
```

but this don't work ... finally I found solution. **This works**!

```
android.library.reference.1=..\\dir\\MyLibrary
```

hope this helps somebody ...

Comment: `android.bat update project --path licensing-library/`  worked. Already had default.properties line with correct path. Was missing build.xml but manually copied that from another app and changed the name. Still didn't work. The update said it updated local.properties (sdk.dir). I don't know what it was before, but should have been correct since I just installed it. I also changed target in project.properties to be the same `android-10` as my project. Not sure that had any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this library, however I find that for Ant builds which need third party jars it's necessary to create a directory 'libs' below your 'my_project_home' (i.e at the same level as 'src'). Drop the jar in there. The targets in main_rules.xml should then be able to find it.

Comment: Yes that is all true. Problem here is that market licensing library is actually not a library (jar file) but is source which has to be compiled and added to classes.dex

Comment: Yes, I see your problem, good question. Other users suggest that as long as you use a relative path, it should work. I see that you have got a relative path, so as long as your sdk base is under users/Boris I can't see where the trouble is, sorry.

Comment: The most funny thing about this is that if I "compile-install" from Eclipse (right click on project -> Run As -> Android Application) it works. When I want to use buildin ant there is error shown above... WTF?

Answer (score 0):

zmeda check the extras LVM folder I think its missing the default.properties file..at least that is what your error message is telling you..

Comment: In my project folder there is default.properties. Actually content of this file is mentioned in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to put a reference to the library project in the build.properties file of your main application. It should look like:

```
android.library.reference.1=../path-to/library-project
```

Then as long as that project also has a working ant build.xml it will build and be included in your app.

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html)

Comment: build.xml doesn't exist in licensing library.

Comment: if build.xml doesn't exist then you are not going to be able to build it with Ant. You will need to create one with the 'android update project' command